# Error launching remote program: launch or suspend in progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.6

I'm suddenly getting this error when launching my app on an actual device but not on the simulator, where it appears to run fine.

I've tried deleting the app from the iPad. I've also tried clearing out `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` as suggested in questions on here for similar (but not identical) error messages.

Anyone have any other ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

When I've had this its normally because the iPad's locked up (and not because of anything on my Mac).  Have you tried rebooting the iPad by holding the power and home buttons?

Comment: D'oh! Can't believe it never occurred to me to check that. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, it happens to me to. But why does this happen so frequently?!?!

Comment: You're not alone, I find that my iPad does this very frequently too.

Comment: Since the latest Xcode this seems to be happening to me all the time!

Comment: My top button is broken! :( My phone is frozen on a black screen haha!

Answer (score 2):

It's probably happening because you interrupt a build that's going on. To fix it, clean your project and re-run it. If your device is still stuck, then do a hard reboot.

Comment: Cleaning the build does nothing when the device gets locked up like this.  Hard reboot fixes the symptom.  Apple needs to fix the actual problem.